# how to consume wcf service hosted by windows service using java script

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, wcf, windows-services

Hi i had a wcf service hosted using windows service and the hosting of service was successfully completed and now my requirment is to consume it in javascript and the service returns table and it was in xml format with column names as tags in it so how to read date in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had got the answer Here is the code written in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = invokeService();
        function invokeService() {
            $(document).ready(function () {


                //   Additional way of calling WCF service using getJSON() JQuery method
                $.getJSON("http://localhost/WcfJsonRestService/Albums/rjinfo", {},
                    function (data) {
                         alert("hello " + data);

                    });
            });
            }


    </script>
```