# How do I consume a WCF service hosted by windows service using java script?

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services, wcf

Let me start off by pointing out that this question was already asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109065/how-to-consume-wcf-service-hosted-by-windows-service-using-java-script). I tried that solution but I get Cross-Origin Request Blocked plus there were no comments on his solution. The thing is I have created my WCF service as a class library and I host it using windows service. Therefore I dont have a web.config file to do this, `crossdomainscriptaccessenabled="true"`.

**EDIT**

My WCF service classes are shown below,

**ICPU.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface ICPU
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetProcessData();
    }
```

**CPU.cs**

```
public class CPU : ICPU
    {
        ProcessDetails pd = new ProcessDetails();
        ProcessLocal pl = new ProcessLocal();
        public string GetProcessData()
        {
            pd.processes = pl.ProcessMonitor();

            string json_response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pd);

            return json_response;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the WCF service a SOAP service, or a RESTful service? And is it emitting JSON or XML or something else?

Comment: try using cors - http://enable-cors.org/index.html

Comment: @Dai I am returning a JSON string from my method. See EDIT.

Comment: For this kind of szenario I would suggest to use a ASP.NET Web API Project.